# MariaDB / MySQL adds DEFAULT NULL to column definition, how to change that?

Tags: mysql, null, mariadb

When I create table with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `change_log` (
  `object_id` int(11)
)
```

MariaDB creates table **change_log** which has **DEFAULT NULL** in it's table definition for object_id column. That is, for the statement:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE change_log
```

it returns:

```
CREATE TABLE `change_log` (
    `object_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

How can I configure mariadb/mysql not to add DEFAULT NULL in this case?

I use MariaDB 10.2.14 on Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

You only must add **DEFAULT NULL** like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `change_log` (
  `object_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: That's not a solution to my problem. I don't want banning NULL in this column, I just don't want DEFAULT NULL. I want no default value there and I want accept NULL there. I can't modify the initial create table statement because it originates in some tool (this is just an example, it's a big mysql dump file, so manual modifications are not an option).

Comment: @JohnM2 - sorry, i have change my answer

Comment: Thanks for the afford, but the behaviour I would like to have is no default value at all. Database engine should throw an error when no value for such a column is supplied. That is the behaviour I have in mysql 5.7.21.

Comment: @JohnM2 MySQL will not throw an error in the case you describe. If you do not provide a value for a column (e.g. in an `insert`), it is the same as providing `null` (hence adding `default null` makes no different at all). Could you provide a sample for the MySQL counterpart you want to mimic? (The table description and the insert statement that fails when you don't provide a value). It might be defined as `not null` as Bernd originally assumed.

Comment: Guys that's right. There can be no default, bu only if NOT NULL is set.  So I think the question has no answer, because my presumptions were not right. But I know something new now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

Do you see `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` or `STRICT_TRANS_MODE`?

What happens when you include (or exclude) those from `@@sql_mode` before the `CREATE TABLE`?  Before the `INSERT`?

Comment: Yes I see those values:

STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
but it is now clear (see Solarflare's and my comment above). Thanks.